# Corollary 7.15 of Spivak's Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

From Spivak's Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry:

> **Corollary 7.15**: If $\omega^{k+1},\dots, \omega^n$ are linearly independent 1-forms in
>    a neighborhood of $p \in M$, then there are 1-forms
>    $\theta^\alpha_\beta$$(\alpha, \beta > k)$ with $$ d\omega^\alpha =
>  \sum_\beta \theta^\alpha_\beta \wedge \omega^\beta $$ if and only if
>    there are functions $f^\alpha_\beta$, $g^\beta$ $(\alpha, \beta > k)$
>    with $$ \omega^\alpha = \sum_\beta f^\alpha_\beta \, dg^\beta.$$

Could someone show me how the proof of this corollary goes? I'm fairly certain you need to use the differential form version of Frobenius theorem, but I'm not sure how.

---

I can see that if I assume there are functions $f^\alpha_\beta$, $g^\beta$ $(\alpha, \beta > k)$
 with $$ \omega^\alpha = \sum_\beta f^\alpha_\beta \, dg^\beta,$$ then taking the exterior derivative of $\omega$ and substituting $dg^\beta = (f^\alpha_\beta)^{-1}\omega^\alpha$ gives $$d\omega^\alpha = df^\alpha_\beta \wedge dg^\beta = df^\alpha_\beta(f^\alpha_\beta)^{-1}\wedge \omega^\beta = \theta^\alpha_\beta \wedge \omega^\beta. $$

Comment: Spivak gives the proof leading in to the statement of the corollary. The point is that the first equations say that the system $\omega^\alpha=0$, $\alpha>k$, is integrable, and this means that there are local coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ so that the integral manifolds are slices $x^\alpha=\text{constant}$. The $g^\beta$ are the $x^\beta$ in that coordinate system.